# Create a patch using WiX with many Components

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.6

I'm using WiX (currently 3.6) to create a setup for my application. Next step is to create patches when something must be changed. As I use heat to create automatically components for a lot of files, those components are referenced using a ComponentGroup. Sadly, the PatchFamily allows only for ComponentRefs and not ComponentGroupRefs. As those components are auto generated, I search a way to enable patch creation.

The way I tried is documented here: [Patchwork](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/)

Currently I'm investigating the possibility to use administrative installs and make a diff between them.

Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what exactly is it that you are trying to do?  Perform an upgrade of the application with new files?  If you really have enough changes that you are using ComponentGroupRefs, then it might just be worth doing an actual upgrade. Patches (at least from my understanding) are meant more for small changes to the program, while upgrades are for large changes effecting numerous files.

Comment: Making patches using purely WiX involves referencing all components in the patch.wxs. The update then compares old and new files and includes only changed ones. As there are generated components from heat I gave ComponentGroups in the main wxs - I do not "know" the components nor can I type them in by hand. Just too many.

Comment: No matter what I foresee problems with this for you.  Patches and upgrades alike work by comparing Component GUID's to find out what is installed and what is not.  If you have no access to the old GUID's and just give everything a new GUID (at least from my experience) you will end up with the program (or at least parts of it) installed twice on the client machine.  It really is hard to work with installations that have numerous files.  My current project has about 10,000 different files spread over 20+ MSI's.  Once the initial setup, however, it is merely a case of maintenance and upkeep.

Comment: As heat produces Guid="*" for Components, exactly what you describe happens. I'm writing my own "heater" that remembers once assigned Guids.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as an answer as it states the problem correctly and I found a solution on my own.